# Mongoose find inside schema collection array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to find the documents which has match inside it's array..

Schema name is food, and here is it

```
var foodSchema = {
    "store_id": String,
    'food': [{
        'dish': String
    }]
};
var store = mongoose.model('store', storeSchema);
module.exports = { store: store, food: food }
```

And here is the controller

```
dbModel.food.find({ 'food.dish': req.body.data }, function(err, foundUsers) {
        res.status(200).json({
            "success": "1",
            "message": foundUsers
        });
    });
```

It's returning empty always, how can i find it  ?

Comment: `req.body.data` value is not in the `food` array that's why you are getting empty array. You need to check exactly what value in the `req.body.data` is being passed to the query.

Answer (score 0):

You also need `var food = mongoose.model('food', foodSchema)`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code is not complete, while you are exporting `{store: store, food:food}`, code is just about showing `store` model. But still considering your `foodSchema`, to find a element matching in array of string. You can try `$in` operator like below:

```
dbModel.food.find({ food: { $in: [req.body.data] } }, function(err, foundUsers) {
    res.status(200).json({
        "success": "1",
        "message": foundUsers
    });
});
```